# Using img tag in View to display static picture

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I'm moving from ASP.NET to MVC and having trouble displaying a simple image. I have a Controller:

```
Public Class LinkedImageController
    Inherits Controller

    ' GET: LinkedImage
    Function Index() As ActionResult
        Return View()
    End Function
End Class
```

and a View:

```
<img src="~/Views/LinkedImage/grey_336x280.gif" alt="Views-LinkedImage" /><!-- Doesn't work -->
<img src="~/Content/LinkedImage/grey_336x280.gif" alt="Content-LinkedImage"/><!-- Works -->
```

I have copies of the image in the Views/LinkedImage folder and the Content/LinkedImage folder and both are set to copy to the output folder.

As you can see from the comments in the View only the `<img...` tag that links to the file under the Content folder displays the image correctly.

While this is only a single image where I'm trying to get to is a design for displaying existing html questionnaires within an MVC framework so I have to work out where the various static files can be stored.

I'm new to MVC so I'm assuming that the image in the View folder cannot be displayed because the routing affects it somehow. Is this correct? If not, why does only one image display?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line in the Web.config of your Views folder blocks direct access to files therein:

```
<system.webServer>
  <handlers>
    <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
      <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Best policy is to put your static content in ~/Content (or another folder you create in the application root directory, if you wish) - you don't want to risk giving a malicious user access to the code in your views.